# OpenCV and Cocoa error "Previous frame inner to this frame"

Tags: cocoa, multithreading, xcode, debugging, gdb

I'm playing with OpenCV in Cocoa program. When I try to call the method with some OpenCV code in the second thread I get "Previous frame inner to this frame (gdb could not unwind past this frame)"

Comment: Sounds like it was trying to go down the stack, but found itself going up instead. I'm not sure how that might have happened—stack smashed?

Comment: Yes, it's very likely the stack has been smashed. Running the code under valgrind should point out the problem.